# Where are the default Eclipse Plugin Development Templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just started looking at developing a plugin for Eclipse and I found a bunch of tutorials, some of which seem out of date (i.e. using old versions of Eclipse).  But I have found one that uses Helios, so it is pretty up to date.  Yet all of them refer to creating the projects using templates.  Whenever I start a new plugin project the list of templates is empty.  Does anyone know where these templates come from?  Is there something specific I need to install within Eclipse to get the templates?  Can I download them separately from somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDE templates are in the org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates plugin. I am using the default Eclipse packaging and this plugin is part of the "distribution". May be you can look into Helios software repository (Help -> Install New Software -> Helios Repository) and see if you can find any features related to PDE UI template.

EDIT: After checking, the PDE templates plugin is part of the PDE feature. As a consequence if you have the PDE installed you should have the templates. What "distribution" of Eclipse did you downloaded from the download page ?

Comment: Every time I was checking the Update packages I was filtering for PDE, after searching through it manually I found Plugin Development Environment.  As soon as I installed this I got all the templates.

Comment: Hey - could you tell me where I find those templates from _inside_ eclipse ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D sorry but I don't know and I am even wondering if this is possible. Maybe you should ask a separate question for this

Comment: No I just meant how to open a new project based on a template - I found it: `New Project > Plug-in Project (give it a name) > Next > Templates`. To open the org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates plugin inside eclipse you just need to import the plugin I guess - see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#importplugins

Answer (score 0):

did you download the Eclipse PDE version?

http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/indigor

or

http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2

for Helios resp.

Not sure where they come from, but they're included in my indigo "RCP & RAP" installation package.

Cheers,
 Rob

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I initially installed eclipse for java development.  I later wanted to add a plug-in to add an editor for a language that currently is not supported. After installing PDE the plugin project template that adds a new language edition to generic and extensible text editor was missing.

I cleared the problem by Help > Check for software updates.  The PDE software just needed to be updated.  After the update the expected plugin was available.